# php does not load scripts when i don't do a var_dump

Tags: php, css, class

I build css links with a function but if I don't do a var_dump on the end, the css will not work. What am I missing or not seeing?

The code:

```
private function buildCssLinks(){
    $files  =   $this->findFiles(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/css","css");

    foreach ($files as $id)
    {
        $pathInfo   =   pathinfo($id);
        $fileName   =   $pathInfo['basename'];

        $files[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/' . $fileName . '">';
    }
    return implode("",$files);
}
```

returns

[1st return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9KC1.png)

but when I add a var dump in my code

```
    private function buildCssLinks(){
    $files  =   $this->findFiles(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/css","css");

    foreach ($files as $id)
    {
        $pathInfo   =   pathinfo($id);
        $fileName   =   $pathInfo['basename'];

        $files[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/' . $fileName . '">';
    }
    var_dump($files);
    return implode("",$files);
}
```

the 2nd return

[2nd return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qYKB.png)

the code that calls the functions __construct

```
  public function __construct($header, $body, $footer)
{
    $this->header   =   $header;
    $this->body     =   $body;
    $this->footer   =   $footer;


    $this->buildHeader();
    $this->buildBody();
    $this->buildFooter();

    $js     =   $this->buildJsLinks();
    $css    =   $this->buildCssLinks();
    $this->header   =   $css;
    $this->footer   =   $js;
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling you need to echo buildCssLinks().

Comment: can you show us the code that calls buildCssLinks?

Comment: @WEBjuju i added the call code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buildCssLinks is returning the html.  But you must then put it into your html somehow.  Perhaps

```
$css = $this->buildCssLinks();
$this->header .= $css;
```

or more likely you need to buildCssLinks first and pass that into header build:

```
$this->css = $this->buildCssLinks();
$this->buildHeader();  // within buildHeader echo your this->css
```

Comment: what does the implode function then ?

Comment: it takes all of the elements of an array and concatenates them with the first argument to implode (which in your case is empty).  so array(1,2,3) imploded is "123" and  implode(",", array(1,2,3)) is "1,2,3", yo.

Comment: i added 


`$js     =   $this->buildJsLinks();
        $css    =   $this->buildCssLinks();
        $this->header   =   $css;
        $this->footer   =   $js;`

Comment: if this is solved, please mark the solution.  if this is not solved, post your updated code and unexpected results, please.